# Как проверить изменился ли файл?

Tags: сеть, delphi, файлы

Для проекта необходимо в реальном времени отслеживать изменение файла на сетевом диске, и сразу загружать последнюю версию.

Сейчас все делаю через таймер и `FileDateToDateTime()`. Клиентов не больше 20ти, но меня все же мучает вопрос - не скажется ли такой метод на производительности и надежности сетевого хранилища? Насколько вредны постоянные запросы?

Как этот же функционал можно реализовать более правильно?

*p.s.: Вариант с клиент-серверным приложением самый-самый крайний, т.к. для него в офисе нет отдельной машины, да и начальство не будет в восторге от такой идеи.*

**Update**
После многочисленных экспериментов решил отказаться от идеи отслеживания файлов в пользу UDP Broadcast. Т.к. изменение файлов происходит в приложениях-клиентах, то я сразу отправляю пакет другим клиентам. Пока что отправляю только уведомление, что что-то поменялось, но, в последствии, переделаю с указанием точного адреса файла.

Comment: > Вариант с клиент-серверным приложением самый-самый крайний, т.к. для него в офисе нет отдельной машины

Да как бы и не обязательно иметь отдельную машину. Что у вас в качестве хранилища? на какой машине сетевые диски?

Comment: Сетевой диск автономный с Ethernet портом, Western Digital. Модель к сожалению не помню, MyBook World, кажется.

Сейчас экспериментирую с `TShellChangeNotifier`, на локальном диске прекрасно отрабатывает, а по сети проверить возможности нет.
Кто подскажет как он работает? По каким параметрам определяет изменения?

Comment: Решение на Delphi можно посмотреть [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/480325/2546083)

Answer (score 5):

Я считаю, что самый лучший вариант в данном случае, это сверять хэш файла.

Я делал приложение такое на шарпе.
Был сервер, на котором хранился файл программы, который постоянно обновлялся.
И было порядка 10-ти машин, на которых приходилось постоянно обновлять файл.
Решил облегчить себе работу, и всё это автоматизировать.
Идея была следующей: у каждого клиента, в трее висит программа, которая через определённый интервал времени должна была каким - то образом проверять, не изменился ли файл. Изначально, мысль была сделать проверку по дате изменения файла, но сказать честно, этот вариант отпал сразу, ибо не всегда при замене(программно во всяком случае) файла, меняется дата его последнего обновления.
Решил сделать следующим образом:
Программа при первом запуске записывала в ini файл хеш нужного файла, и в последствии, через какой - то интервал времени сравнивала текущий хэш файла, с тем, что был записал в ini файл. ) Если изменений нет - молчим. Если есть - выводим сообщение, где пользователю предлагается обновить файл. )
Работает отлично. Бегать больше не приходилось. )

Comment: Именно постоянного обращения к файлу я и пытаюсь избежать. А для вычисления его контральной суммы мне и вовсе придется загружать его целиком. 

Вопрос остается открытым. 

А кто скажет по поводу того насколько это вредно для жесткого диска?
10-20 клиентов опрашивают файл раз в пять секунд. 115200 обращений за рабочий день. Это много по меркам жесткого диска или он проглотит и не заметит?

Comment: О диске в Вашем случае можете не беспокоиться. Таблица метаданных открытого в данный момент (любым процессом) файла (в *nix inode) закеширована в ОЗУ (в ядре). Поэтому запрос о времени изменения такого файла (в *nix stat()) диск не затрагивает.

Беспокоиться Вам если и есть о чем, так о нагрузке на сеть, ну и связанную с обменами по сети нагрузку на "процессор" (на обеих сторонах).

Comment: Я не думаю, что у Вас файл весит Больше 50метров. Если не меньше 10 - 20. ) А это соответственно небольшая нагрузка. К тому же, зачем ставить интервал в 5сек.? Если файл обновится на одну минуту позже? Недопустимо? :)

Comment: Если я просто загружаю данные из файла используя TRichEdit.Lines.LoadFromFile() или TIniFile.Create() он считается открытым? Или он обращается один раз к файлу и закрывает его?

Comment: Я не знаю, как реализована работа с файлами в делфи. Я думаю, что если файл надо закрывать вручную, то есть такой метод. :)
Типа: TIniFile.Close(), или как - то так. :)

Comment: Даже если файл уже закрыт всеми, кто обращался к нему, метаданные тут же из кэша не исчезнут. Эта информация будет удаляться, когда в кэше не останется свободного места для новых данных, т.е. в зависимости от интенсивности запросов к новым объектам файловой системы.

Только сейчас заметил: "10-20 клиентов опрашивают файл раз в пять секунд". Думаю, для (RPC stat()), это невысокая нагрузка.

Answer (score 2):

SMB кеширует запросы к статистике файла, в том числе к mtime, так что сильно переживать за нагрузку не надо :)

Answer (score 2):

Если надо получать точные сведения - какой файл или папка изменён, какие изменения с ним произошли и в какой последовательности - для этого надо применять механизм, построенный на вызовах функций: [CreateFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [ReadDirectoryChangesW()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [CloseHandle()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Пример использования на Delphi можно найти [здесь](http://www.cyberforum.ru/delphi-beginners/thread972061.html#post5183723).

Comment: А почему бы не использовать FileSystemWatcher из System.IO из .NET. Можно отслеживать изменение файла и каталога хоть по сети. Тем более есть Delphi.NET

Comment: Delphi.NET кто-то использует в реальных проектах? По моему это была мертворожденная версия Delphi. Разве нет?

Comment: Не знаю, просто из всех предложенных вариантов (с хэшами и пингами) это просто самый разумный вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить еще вариант:
Монтировать сетевую папку как диск и попробовать отслеживать изменения как в локальной директории. Но за работоспособность не ручаюсь.

Comment: На счет хэш файла не согласен. Здесь можно подробней почитать http://www.webdelphi.ru/2011/08/monitoring-izmenenij-v-direktoriyax-i-fajlax-sredstvami-delphi-chast-1/

Comment: И еще кажется в JEDI есть компонент, основанный как раз на этих событиях, что описаны в приведенной ссылке.

Answer (score 0):

А почему бы не использовать FileSystemWatcher из System.IO из .NET. Можно отслеживать изменение файла и каталога хоть по сети. Тем более есть Delphi.NET